# Question mark inside XML file without encoding produces errors while trying to load it

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to get all the elements in a selected "Xpath location" and add them to a comboBox/ drop down list.

I tried to select all these elements by using the Xpath query : /@* with the Select method from the XpathNodeIterator.

The problem is that it return an iterator which does not move forward, in fact, it says it has no childs and its not allowing me to convert the iterator neither to an xmlElement or node so that I could at least search inside them.

This is the code :

```
 while (anIterator.MoveNext())
            {
                //im trying to select  all nodes  of selected path which and return them to an iterator
                secondIterator = anIterator.Current.Select("/@*");                    

                while (secondIterator.MoveNext())
                {
                    aNode = new Nodes();
                    aNode.Name = anIterator.Current.MoveToFirstChild().ToString();
                    nodeList.Add(aNode);
                }
                nodeList.Add(aNode);
            }
```

Any solution to get all the elements in the current node ?

Comment: What's the XML? How can we guess?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely harder to answer without the XML file you're working with, and without you telling us what you're hoping to see, and what you're currently seeing.

Here are some observations:

The '@' character in your XPath suggests you're trying to get all of the attributes of the current Node. The '/' tells Path to start at the root of the DOM.

If you're trying to get all the elements under the current node, you might want to change to "./*"

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the `@`, which indicates that you want to select the child *attributes*, not child elements.  (See http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev).

Try `anIterator.Current.Select("*")` to get the child elements.  If you want all descendant elements (not just immediate children), try `anIterator.Current.Select(".//*")`